# Appending a value to a list inside a list

Tags: python, append

A simple question regarding the appending rule of list.

So the code is

```
list = [1,2,3,4]
for x in [list] #Yes a list in a list:
    x.append(2)

print(x)
print(list)
```

The result of the two print is both [1,2,3,4,2]. I can see why print(x) outputs 1,2,3,4,2 but I didnt update the list yet but somehow the list is also updated.

Is there a hidden rule behind this? or is it just a default setting I need to memorize.

Thanks

Two prints have the same output and I wanna know why

Comment: Your `for` loop only has one iteration. In effect, your loop can be replaced by: `x = list;x.append(2)`, which is the same as `list.append(2)`

Comment: A side note - don't use `list` as variable name

Comment: I recommend never to declare a variable with the name `list`. This is because once you've done this, you overwrite the build in function `list()` in your namespace. So for example, if later on in your code you want to convert a string into a list, like `list("abcde")`, you will get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a similar code to yours, I broken down to explain it better:

```
sublist = [1,2,3,4]
```

`sublist` is a simple 1d array.

```
li = [sublist]
```

`li` is a list containing `sublist`, effectivly a 2d array.

```
for x in li:
```

If you iterate over `li`, `x` is each element of `li`, so first a final iteration, `x` will be the list `[1,2,3,4]`.

```
x.append(2)
```

Then you append 2 to `x` so you are effectivly appending to `sublist`.

The complete code looks like this:

```
sublist = [1,2,3,4]
li = [sublist] 
print(li) # => [[1, 2, 3, 4]]
for x in li:
    print(x) # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
    x.append(2) # appending 2 to x (i.e [1, 2, 3, 4] <= 2) that is contained in li
print(x) # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 2]
print(li) # => [[1, 2, 3, 4, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Lists in python are by reference, not by value.
inner list in `[list]` is referring to the same list as outside `list`
Therefore, the append you do is visible in both references (they are the same list).

I've made a simpler example that illustrates the same point:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [a]
b[0].append(4)
print(a)
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```